# P&T Assets not functioning correctly after migrating to new server environment

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic, file-manager, staging-server

After moving my site to a staging environment I'm no longer able to view any images within the Assets portion of the CP or upload files to any Assets related fields. I'm also unable to update the indexes within Assets (it just appears to freeze).

I've double checked the following:

- That the Assets and EE cache folder have proper permissions.
- That the paths are correct in the upload destination's File Upload Preferences.
- That I'm able to successfully upload to the folder via EE's native File Manager.

I started poking around in the DB and noticed that in the `exp_assets_index_data` table all of the `uri` fields had the incorrect file path in them (they're all showing the path from my local environment). I ran a `REPLACE` query in MySQL and fixed the paths, but still am still experiencing the same issues.

The site is running EE 2.7.2 (build 20131008) and the latest version of Assets 2.5.

Any thoughts on what might be happening or tips on how to get things back up and running would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did end up finding out what the issue was, but I suspect something got borked in the DB when moving between environments. I ended up pushing a fresh install into staging and working with backup copy of the DB and all is working as expected again. Strange internet magic.

I'm posting this as an answer because I'm pretty sure this was caused by user error somewhere along the way vs. being an issue with Assets itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact solution but it may help none-the-less.

Have you tried Deploy Helper?

It will show you all the places a path may be causing havoc.

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/deeploy-helper
http://www.hopstudios.com/software/deeploy_helper/

(You can download it off their website to try before you buy.  This has helped me many times)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't used that, but I did use a similar add-on (REElocate) to double-check all of the paths.